# Lotus notes database migration to Db2

Tags: db2, migration, lotus-notes

I want to migrate the lotus notes DB to DB2 , I got read the answers like convert to CSV file format using scripts and then import the CSV file in DB2. Can some one help me how to convert the data to CSV ....and how much time it will take if the data size is approximately 30 MB ?

Thanks
Raj

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty trivial to export Notes data to CSV.

You can modify a class I wrote to export views into CSV. Jus have it process all the fields in the document. You can find the source code at  http://blog.texasswede.com/export-notes-view-to-excel-with-multi-value-fields/

If you want to export the documents as XML and include attachments and/or embedded images you can look at this tool I wrote:
http://www.texasswede.com/websites/texasswede.nsf/Page/Notes%20XML%20Exporter

30 MB is not much, it probably will take you longer to write the agent than to run it. :)